# Audiokit MIDI initialisation is confusing

Tags: ios, swift, core-audio, coremidi, audiokit

CoreMIDI terminology is already super confusing and badly documented, and Audiokit isn't helping as much as I wished it might.

As far as I can tell, each application is supposed to have one instance of a midi client reference (`MIDIClientRef`). Audiokit has the `AKMIDI` class that creates a new client reference for each `AKMIDI` instance, and instances are being created left, right and center (including the initialization of each `AKMIDIInstrument`, `AKCallbackInstrument` and `AKMIDISampler` instance). All of these also create endpoints with hardcoded names in their built-in constructors so I don't see how I'm supposed to make ones that have proper names.

The top price goes to `AKMIDISampler`, whose source first says:

```
/// Initialize the MIDI Sampler
public override init() {
    super.init()
    enableMIDI()
}
```

And then on the following few lines:

```
/// Enable MIDI input from a given MIDI client
/// This is not in the init function because it must be called AFTER you start AudioKit
///
/// [snipped parameter comments for brevity]
open func enableMIDI(_ midiClient: MIDIClientRef = AKMIDI().client, name: String = "MIDI Sampler")
```

(Note that it **IS** in the init function)

I would be super happy to either hear some clarification about general usage guidelines (do I need to override everything?) or links to documentation/articles explaining this in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just fixed that issue with #1141 PR.
https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/pull/1141/files

You can point to the develop branch on your podfile until the next release.

```
pod 'AudioKit', :git => 'https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit.git', :branch => 'develop'
```

Comment: Your PR seems to address the naming issue and there have been other improvements to the develop branch that take care of the midi client ref issue, so I will mark this the accepted answer. The documentation is still misleading. I can live with it, but leaving this comment for anyone who might find the question.